# sysfunc not working.

Tags: sas

What's wrong with this sysfunc call?

```
%let mystring = hello world;

%let mycount =  %sysfunc(count(&mystring, 'hello')); 

%put &mycount;
```

outputs

```
[PUT]  0
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are outside of a datastep, you don't need quotation marks around `hello` (quotation marks are part of the string, not its delimiters).
So this should work:

```
%let mystring = hello world;
%let mycount =  %sysfunc(count(&mystring, hello)); 
%put &mycount;
```

One more example to illustrate what's going on here,
this would also print 1:

```
%let mystring = 'hello' world;
%let mycount =  %sysfunc(count(&mystring, 'hello')); 
%put &mycount;
```